# Imported framework doesn't find framework supposed to be inside it

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-frameworks

I have my own Cocoa Touch Framework, it has a imported framework linked to work properly

As shown on the image below when I try to import my framework to an app project, I get the error:

Missing required module 'X'

Even when the referred 'X' (module/framework) is copied together.

I tried:

- Copy file on build phases
- Set frameworks Search Paths

And many other ways and it never find the module inside it self.

[image: framework]

Comment: Go to Build Phases -> Link Binary with library and select your framework. Also, select your framework in Embed Framework option.

Comment: I already set my framework on this options of the app project, my problem is that my framework can't find the framework inside it

Comment: Do you want to import one framework into another or one framework to an app project? Try this link: https://medium.com/john-lewis-software-engineering/adding-a-third-party-framework-inside-a-first-party-framework-in-xcode-3ba58cfd08da

Comment: I want to import a X.framework into my A.framework. I already succeeded to do this without errors. So I can build my own framework with this another inside but when I import my "A" framework on an app project and try "Import A" I have the error Missing required module 'X'

Comment: Oh. Can you try importing both X and A framework to your project? Add both to Build Phases.

Comment: Ah yes I'm already using it this way just because only this way that worked. I'm wondering if there is a way to bring it built-in together or is it really the only way?

Comment: I think that is the only way. Because I was in a similar situation and I did the same thing. Anyway, I'll just write it as an answer for others.

Comment: I think it is the only way thus. I tried set framework search path many ways and noting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import both frameworks, add both those frameworks to :

- > General -> Frameworks, Libraries & Embedded Content : Add framework
  >   and choose Embed & Sign.
- > Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries
- > Build Phases -> Copy Files